# Can't seem to create a master key. Error message: 15247

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

When trying to create my master key in Azure SQL database (as per the docs instructions), I get the following error message:

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> User does not have permission to perform this action.

However, I'm currently logged in as the server admin when running this query, how is it that I'm unable to do so when I'm the owner?

Comment: Please post the T-SQL you're using, and provide a link to the article/instructions you're referring to.

Comment: It would be this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-a-database-master-key?view=sql-server-ver16 and for the T-SQL, just what the article gives as an example (but obviously changing out the password).

Comment: You say you're logged-in as the server-admin, but _have you made sure_? What does `sys.fn_my_permissions` show?

Comment: In the link above it says "Expand System Databases, right-click master and then click New Query." - pretty sure that creating it in `master` won't work in Azure SQL database. Have you tried creating it in the context of your user database?